# Why does Ionic3 -Splash Screen generating error?

Tags: ionic3, splash-screen

I am getting an error while using

```
ionic cordova resources --splash
```

```
ionic cordova resources --splash --force
√ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
√ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
× Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - failed!
HTTP Error 400: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload
```

Comment: It seems the size of image is different. It should be `3732x3732`.

Comment: Thanks a lot at solved my problem